# Unknown type name in open source project

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to get an open source project to compile. The compiler throws an error on this line

```
string   Int_StrN     (const int val, const streamsize count); //unknown type name 'streamsize'
```

I take this to mean that that, well, the type is not defined.

There are four include files and none of these files define streamsize. Nor is streamsize defined in the file itself.

```
#include "bh.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
```

But I'm pretty sure that this code compiled and built on someone's system (it is from a moderately-active open source project). So how can the original coder have used streamsize without defining the type?

Comment: By the way, did you ever consider [googling for "streamsize"](http://www.google.com/search?q=streamsize)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I googled the compiler error and not the word srreamsize because I thought streamsize was a custom type unique to the project. I did not know that "streamsize" was commonly used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The header you need is

```
#include <ios>
```

The reason why it works for others is, that the header is implicitly included from some of the other headers. This is not guaranteed, so some people, like you, run into trouble with it. Ask the author to explicitly add the required `#include`.

Comment: or `<iostream>` which is guaranteed to include `<ios>` (in C++11, but it's very likely in C++03 that the library does)

Comment: @ipc Yes, if you need other stuff from `<iostream>` as well, that is a good option.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::streamsize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) is a standard C++ type, from the [`<ios>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ios) header.

Comment: It's is ridiculous why this answer is not getting upvotes or accepted. As I remember, this answer was written before Daniel's and is basically the same thing

Comment: @khajvah Exactly one second before :-)  Normally I remove duplicate answers, but I included links, where no one else did.

Comment: @khajvah This answer doesn't explain why the code compiled for others. But +1 for the links :)

Comment: @DanielFrey by `from the <ios> header` he made it obvious why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @khajvah The question wasn't "How to fix it", the OP asked "So how can the original coder have used streamsize without defining the type?".

Answer (score 0):

string is declared in namespace std.

```
std::string Int_StrN     (const int val, const std::streamsize count);
```

or:

using namespace std;

```
string Int_StrN     (const int val, const streamsize count);
```

Comment: `unknown type name 'streamsize'` not string